# How to log when ArrayList copies its internal array?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, profiling

In Android, when you add an element to an `ArrayList`, it puts it into an array behind the scenes. If the array is full, it creates a new one, twice as big (making it a dynamic array):

```
public boolean add(E object) {
    Object[] a = array;
    int s = size;
    if (s == a.length) {
        Object[] newArray = new Object[s +
                (s < (MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT / 2) ?
                 MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT : s >> 1)];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, s);
        array = a = newArray;
    }
    a[s] = object;
    size = s + 1;
    modCount++;
    return true;
}
```

(Source is from [Google's implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/d43b9ef/luni/src/main/java/java/util/ArrayList.java#103).)

The `System.arraycopy()` call may take some time. To measure performance (in a game loop), I'd like to **log when this call takes place**. How can I do this?

(I tried extending ArrayList, and copying the code of this method into my new class, but the IDE says `Cannot resolve symbol 'array'` (which should be a field in the built-in `ArrayList` class), plus this field is package-private (in the code under the link above), so I don't think I could access it from my package. I can't look into the source code of the built-in ArrayList class either.)

Comment: Write your own similar implementation and log it.

Comment: copy paste the `ArrayList` into a new class file and then use that

Comment: do you have this line in your own ArrayList implementation? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/d43b9ef/luni/src/main/java/java/util/ArrayList.java#62

Comment: You could try to simply copy *all* of the ArrayList class into your own CustomArrayList ... and add logging there.

Comment: Or try to create your own System class as a proxy, log what you want,  and load it instead of Legacy System class. System and ArrayList are in rt.jar.